# How to think about inequalities in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

My question is kind of vague, but I'm wondering how to think about many inequalities that appear in real analysis. For example, I don't really see why Holder's Inequality *should* be true, and its proof is quite tricky and not revealing. And Holder's inequality is much simpler compared to inequalities regarding the Marcinkiewicz integral or the Hardy Littlewood maximal function. How does one wrap one's head around these? Reading the proofs is easy but understanding *why* they are true seems much much harder, and something I have to get better at.

Comment: Keep studying, immerse yourself in mathematics, be content with understanding something well enough to be able to apply it to problems, and then after 5 to 10 years (maybe as little as 1 year if you're lucky), something will click and you'll gain a whole new understanding.

Comment: Many things in mathematics **are not** easy to see geometrically or intuitive. This is one of the reasons why mathematics develop from more than 2000 years. Moreover: from the principle of XX century appear that is known as *formalism*, what is a consequence of the impossibility to "prove" results just using intuition.

Comment: Note though that understanding the proof of some theorem, in this case, Holders inequality, implies you see why they *should* be true. It might not me an intuitive theorem at first glance, but this is the case for many many theorems, and some will never get intuitive, because some simply aren't.

Comment: Holder's inequality is just a weighted version of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and the latter follows from the triangle inequality by interpolation/amplification. At some point, you have to be able to replace pure geometric intuition with something more deep - it is like developing a further abstraction layer, allowing you to *believe* and understand, even if you cannot *see*.